# Attach NDIS LWF driver to a Virtual Network Adapter? (Kerio)

Tags: wdk, windows-kernel, ndis

We have an NDIS LWF driver, and it seems like it cannot get attached to Virtual Network Adapters, for example the one that Kerio Control VPN client creates (Kerio Virtual Network).
When i try to install the NDIS LWF in the network adapter manually by giving it our INF file (Install -> service -> Have disk), the driver doesn't appear in the network service list.

Then i found out that i if add nolower in the FilterMediaTypes in the inf file, it does appear in the network service list, but even then, when i click on OK, it doesn't get added to the list of items and doesn't get attached.

My question is, How can i attach to this Kerio Virtual Network Adapter in order to monitor its packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWFs cannot bind to a network interface that has `HKR, Ndi\Interfaces,LowerRange,,nolower` in its INF. Generally speaking, the network interface *ought* to have at least one real LowerRange, and it's reasonable to ask the vendor to add one. For whatever it's worth, we (the Windows OS team) originally shipped the Bluetooth PAN adapter with `nolower`, and then later realized [we needed to update it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/an-application-that-uses-the-filter-driver-cannot-intercept-any-incoming-or-outgoing-packets-by-using-a-bluetooth-device-that-supports-the-tethering-feature-in-windows-7-08bd5047-8fb4-3ebb-1673-448c930451dc) to have *something* there, so LWFs could bind to it. Perhaps that anecdote helps motivate this vendor to update their INF.

If the NDIS datapath uses a 14 byte Ethernet-like header and is roughly compatible with Ethernet's ideas of unicast & multicast, then `ethernet` is the correct thing to put in `LowerRange`. [See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/specifying-binding-interfaces) for more details.

It's not supported to try and add the `nolower` token to your LWF driver INF's `FilterMediaTypes`; you can't reasonably expect to bind to any unknown type of interface. What if the next network adapter indicates packets in some yet-to-be-invented framing layer — how could your LWF possibly make sense of those packets? For that reason, `nolower` is not a binding interface; it's a special token that means "the empty list".

LWFs also cannot bind to CoNDIS network adapters. This is simply because the LWF programming model has never been extended to cover all the additional signaling for connection management.

I am not personally familiar with the "Kerio" network interface — I don't know if it has `nolower` in its INF or whether it's CoNDIS (`!ndiskd` would tell you this). If it's the former, you should ask that vendor to update their INF.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jeffery. Further investigation showed that it indeed does have LowerRange nolower in its inf file. So how can we monitor its packets in this case? What are our options? (Assuming asking Kerio to change their INF file is not an option)

Comment: For example maybe changing the corresponding Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\xxxx\Ndi\Interfaces\LowerRange to ethernet instead of nolower?

Comment: Nevermind.. i forgot to add ndis5 to the HKR, Ndi\Interfaces,LowerRange, and that's why i was not able to attach to it.. Anyways, i assume attaching to nolowers will not do any real harm tho right? Even if we someday attach to some weird unknown adapter, worst case scenario is that we can't understand the packet contents and we pass it along (we just check the NBLs, and if they are OK, pass it along, otherwise block), and won't get any BSOD... right?

Comment: Alright this is getting really weird.. Turns out adding nolower to FilterMediaTypes of my inf file doesn't even matter in Windows 10 (unlike Windows 7), and i only need to add ndis5 to my Ndi\Interfaces,LowerRange... What?? Can you make any sense out of this? Because at first i was trying to change the Ndi\Interfaces,LowerRange nolower of Kerio to ethernet but found out that it doesn't help in Windows 10, and seems like it's because the only thing that matters in Windows 10 is Ndi\Interfaces,LowerRange of my own inf file and not theirs ?!

Comment: Setting `LowerRange` to anything other than `nolower` is not supported for LWFs - even if it seems to work now, I can't promise the OS will keep behaving the same way. The real problem here is the 3rd party network adapter; I can't support any attempts to circumvent the system.

Comment: Unfortunately we contacted Kerio, and they refused to change their INF.. So what are our options right now? Mostly i just want to make sense of what's happening, meaning why in Windows 10 i only need to add ndis5 to my lowerrange and in windows 7 i need to add nolower to my FilterMediaTypes? And why setting their Ndi\Interfaces\LowerRange to ethernet (in their registry key i mentioned in above comments) doesn't fix this in windows 10? I wish i could've just said to the customer that this isn't supported, but they need us to attach to this Kerio adapter no matter what..

Comment: The OS respects the NIC driver's decision here - there's no feature to say "my driver is right and that driver is wrong." (If there were such a feature, then a NIC vendor would likely come to us and ask how they can override a LWF's override....) I understand that you may have found some tricks to circumvent the binding rules, but I hope you can also understand that we (the Windows Networking team) cannot support tricks like that.

Comment: That's understandable. But would it be possible to at least add the statement that NDIS LWF drivers cannot attach to adapters with LowerRange nolower, to the MSDN docs? I'm asking because we need to at least provide a proof to our customer that this is officially not supported, and the nolower description in the page you provided in the answer doesn't state this directly (Note that most customers are not very technical). Should i open an issue for that doc page?

Comment: Yeah we can always improve the docs. Please do file an issue, and I'll make sure we get the right wording on there